# How to use RTCMediaConstraints on iOS

Tags: ios, webrtc

To create a new offer:

```
[_peerConnection createOfferWithDelegate:self
                               constraints:[self defaultOfferConstraints]];

- (RTCMediaConstraints *)defaultOfferConstraints {
  NSArray *mandatoryConstraints = @[
      [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"OfferToReceiveAudio" value:@"true"],
      [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"OfferToReceiveVideo" value:@"true"]
  ];
  RTCMediaConstraints* constraints =
      [[RTCMediaConstraints alloc]
          initWithMandatoryConstraints:mandatoryConstraints
                   optionalConstraints:nil];
  return constraints;
}
```

When i changed true to false,it seems it has nothing to do with `RTCSessionDescription`.  i printed it in

```
- (void)peerConnection:(RTCPeerConnection *)peerConnection
    didCreateSessionDescription:(RTCSessionDescription *)sdp
                          error:(NSError *)error
```

Questions:

- Does constraints has something to do with RTCSessionDescription?
- Which keys are RTCPair supported?

Comment: These options (constraints is a misnomer in the new spec) should only make a difference when you're **not** adding audio and video before creating the offer. Does that help?

Comment: Unless the offerer adds audio or sets `OfferToReceiveAudio=true`, the answerer cannot add audio.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: I set `OfferToReceiveAudio=false` however it also contains audio in my [offer SDP](https://pastebin.com/iY9h0SVS).